# How do I write this Cron Expression?

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to write a cron expression for a job which should run every 3 days at 9AM GMT. This is what I am writing

```
"0 0 9/72 ? * ?"
```

But I get it's as an invalid cron expression because I suppose there can not be two question marks in that. So how should I create a cron job for my use case?

I can not put a * as that would mean the cron must run every day, which it shouldn't.

Comment: `0 0 */3 0 0` would give you every 3rd day, except at the end of the month. what you want isn't really expressible with cron's options. a better option would be to just schedule the job once, then have the job reschedule itself for `+3` days with `at` instead...

Comment: @MarcB I don't think it "isn't really expressible with cron's options". Its seems quiet a common thing to do using cron expressions. Only I am not able to find a way to do it.

Comment: you have fixed numbers, and you have `/` divisors. */3 will give you ever 3 days, but at the end of the month, depending on WHICH month it is, you'll get a much shorter interval: 1,4,...,[28/29/30/31]->1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grails & quartz-scheduler, the right syntax would be :

```
"0 0 9 */3 * ?"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0 9 */3 * * <Your Command>
```

This will run the job every 3 days at 9:00 AM.

[Cron Syntax.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)